# I got spoiled about AoT Should I still wait for the anime?

Tags: attack-on-titan

I got spoiled on Reddit. He said

> That sasha's and hange's are dead

I didn't read past that. Now the real question is

How much of a spoiler is this really? Is it still worth waiting for the new season, or is this basically the plot of this season.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is most definitely still worth waiting for the next season. The spoiler of losing a character is always a harsh one, as you will now be anticipating it. However, this is not the main point the plot is driving towards. And there is still a lot to learn about titans, and the world beyond the wall.

Attack on Titan tends to cover around 30 chapters per season. Hence season 3 part 2 ended at chapter 90. And with the 30 chapter average the spoiled part will be part of the season as well considering The spoiler you received originates from

> chapter 105, and can probably be expected halfway through the season.

And in the future if you do not want to be spoiled, I would recommend not going to fora and communities discussing the source material, such a for example Reddit. As the chance you will be spoiled regarding content is fairly high.